# ADODB Searching for Record by using the known primary key

Tags: javascript, sql, client-side, ado, adodb

I need your help,

I can't seem to be able to search for a record using the primary key. I am using client side javascript (adodb) for this.

The function below should theoretically work, what am I doing wrong?

```
//====================================================================================
function rssims_save() {
//====================================================================================
var cn          =   new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection")
var rs          =   new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset")
var SQL
var dbName      =   "rssims.mdb"
var dbPath      =   "G:\\AS\\Asf\\ASF\\RSSIMS\\db\\"

var id          = document.getElementById("f0").value

alert("function running")

    alert(id)

    SQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_rssims WHERE [ID] = '" + id + "'"

    cn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + dbPath + dbName + "")

    rs.Open(SQL, cn, 1, 2)

    alert(rs.fields(1).value)

    cn.Close


}//end of function
```

Comment: Wow -- client-side sql.  That really seems like an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: Like, really, really, melt your application bad.